# How to select the next text field after a key pressed (ENTER) in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I am making a login GUI and after I enter the username, I want to hit ENTER key and it will select the password text field. How can I achieve this?

My attempt:

```
@FXML
    void userNameKeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
            passWord.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like this should work, did you test if you're entering the method and what the event.getCode() is returning?

Comment: Hi Matt, I debugged and checked, the event.getCode() returned "ENTER", so I think it's the requestFocus() function problem.

Comment: What about tab, does that cycle the focus as expected?

Comment: Yes tab works because my password text field is next to username text field. Enter still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to compile a more complete example. Eg maybe a simple fxml and where it goes wrong. Here is an example that works, and it uses most of the ingredients you are.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;


public class TextFields extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("text field");
        TextField a = new TextField();
        TextField b = new TextField();

        a.setOnKeyPressed( evt ->{
            System.out.println(KeyCode.ENTER + ", " + evt.getCode());
            if(evt.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
                System.out.println("entered");
                b.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setLeft(a);
        root.setRight(b);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 100));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

This code creates a frame with 2 text fields, if you press enter in the left one, you will move to the right one.

Comment: Hey, I will run some test using this source code and let you know!

Comment: @WhyMyCodeLong I tried it using keypressed, and it works fine, plus the keycode is corrent now. I have updated the example.

Comment: Hi Matt, this code works perfectly, sorry for the late response. Thank you sir!!!!!